# Why lambda (regularization paramter) in predict can be different from lambda for fitting model?

Tags: r, cross-validation, glmnet

`lambda` is the parameter of regularization. I'm talking in the context of `glmnet`, and this may be a question generally applied for any model with regularization.

I though `glmnet` calculates the coefficients in the model based on the `lambda sequence` for fitting model. So the result doesn't have the model for other `lambda` values. But why I can still do prediction using other `lambda` values?

```
library(glmnet)
library(ISLR)

data(Caravan)

y = dta$Purchase
x = as.matrix( dta[ , -which(colnames(dta)=='Purchase') ] )

lam1 = 10^(-10:-1)

lr = glmnet(x, y, family='binomial', lambda = lam1)
lr
preds = predict(lr, x, lam1*3, type = "response") # prediction using other lambda
```

---

I ask this because of this:

I roughly know that `lambda`, when not given by user, is generated in `glmnet` based on the data.

`cv.glmnet` firstly run `glmnet` for all the data (I call it `model 0`), and then run `glmnet` for each folder (for a k-folder cv, it's k times, and I call them `model 1-k`).

The purpose to run `glmnet` for all the data (`model 0`) is to get the lambda sequence (call it `lambda-0 seq`) to be used in cv [see P5 in [1](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/glmnet.pdf)].

Then `cv.lognet` is called and it calculates the cv, using `lambda-0 seq`. First, the values in `lambda-0 seq` that don't work with `model 1-k` are ruled out. Prediction is then made using `model 1-k` and `lambda-0 seq`.

Relevant code in `cv.glmnet`

```
glmnet.object = glmnet(x, y, weights = weights, offset = offset, lambda = lambda, ...)
lambda = glmnet.object$lambda
# has run glmnet once to get the lambda seq, and now use it for cv

fun = paste("cv", class(glmnet.object)[[1]], sep = ".")  # here fun = cv.lognet
cvstuff = do.call(fun, list(outlist, lambda, x, y, weights, offset, foldid, type.measure, grouped, keep))
# outlist is model 1-k
```

and `cv.lognet`: (See the source code of these functions for more please.)

```
mlami = max( sapply( outlist, function(obj) min(obj$lambda) ) )
# ignore lambda doesn't work for every subset
which_lam = lambda >= mlami

#prediction for each folder
fitobj = outlist[[i]]
preds = predict(fitobj, x[which, , drop = F], s = lambda[which_lam], offset = off_sub, type = "response") #use lambda-0 seq for pred in model 1-k
```

My question is why `lamdba-0 seq` can be passed to `model 1-k` to do prediction? `Model 1-k` should only have models (coefficients) at their only `lambda sequence`. Any help's appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I have e Question regarding to that. Maybe you can have a look into.https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350659/the-lambda-sequence-in-cv-glmnet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, the package can produce another fit of the model or use linear interpolation.

From the documentation of predict.glmnet:

```
If exact=TRUE, and predictions are to made at values of s not included in the 
original fit, these values of s are merged with object$lambda, and the model
is refit before predictions are made. If exact=FALSE (default), then the predict function 
uses linear interpolation to make predictions for values of s that do not
coincide with those used in the fitting algorithm. Note that exact=TRUE is fragile
when used inside a nested sequence of function calls. predict.glmnet() needs
to update the model, and expects the data used to create it to be around.
```

Comment: I am trying to recode the cv.glmnet. However I am struggling at the same point. If I am supplying my own lambda sequence the results are identical. But as in the case above, the cv.glmnet is computing its own sequence for every fold i and then use the lambda 0-seq for the object of every fold for prediction. Hence the coefficients of fitobject regarding to lambda-0-sec differ, if we are supplying our own lambda sequence (the same sequence for every fold) or using the default Lambda Option. How can I implement this interpolation by myself to get the same results ?